# La función __del__(self) no se ejecuta

Tags: python, poo, manejo-de-memoria, objeto

tengo la siguiente función especial para un objeto:

```
def __del__(self):

    print "objeto Usuario eliminado"

    with open("users/%s.piuser" %self.id, "w") as f:

        dicc = {"ultimo_uso":self.ultimo_uso,
                "ultimos_jugadores":self.ultimos_jugadores,
                "reputacion":self.reputacion,
                "picante":self.ajustes.picante,
                "emparejador":self.ajustes.emparejador}

        self.json_dump(dicc, f, indent=2)

    if self.partida:

        self.bot.send_message(chat_id=str(self.id),
                              text="Se ha cerrado tu partida, para continuar usa /start")
```

El objeto tiene una variable `self.partida` que en muchos momentos tiene valor `None`, y hasta donde he podido observar la función no se ejecuta en caso de que el valor no sea `None`.

He puesto ese `print "test"` para ver cuando la función se ejecuta, y la mayor parte de las veces cuando elimino el objeto de la memoria (el script llega a su fin) no llega a esa línea, y todo esto sin dar ningún error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado el problema y a pesar de ser mi pregunta voy a responder por que lo que he visto me parece interestante:

Por un momento pensé que no tenía absolutamente nada que ver con que `self.partida` fuese `None` o no, y en parte es verdad, pero la cuestión es que el contenido de la variable consigue que no se ejecute `__del__()`

Todo tiene que ver con el *garbage collector* que usa Python, y que no siempre elimina referencias ciclicas; me explico:

El *garbage collector* elimina de la memoria todos todas esas `variables`, `objetos`, etc. que no tienen ninguna referencia. Es decir, que si la variable `usuario` apunta a una instancia `Usuario()` y ejecutas `del usuario`se elimina la instancia, no sólo la variable que apunta a esa instancia.

En este caso el problema esta en que en `self.partida` se colocarían instancias de un objeto `Partida()`, que a su vez tenia una variable `self.padre` que apunta a la instancia del objeto `Usuario`que lo contiene, creandose así un ciclo de refencias, y consiguendo que al terminar el script el *garbage collector* no ejecutase `__del__()`para ninguno de los dos objetos.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Ventura, por supuesto que haces bien en autocontestarte si sabes la causa del problema. Esto permite que otros usuarios con un problema similar tengan posibles soluciones contrastadas. Justo iba a agregar un comentario preguntando sobre que contenia `self.partida` cuando no era `None` porque sospechaba de algo así. Saludos y gracias por compartir.

Comment: Estás muy cerca, aunque habría que puntualizar algunas cosas. El GC se dedica a buscar y eliminar *"referencias cíclicas"*; pero las instancias se eliminan cuando desaparecen todas las referencias que tenía (el contador de referencias sea cero). Mientras haya una referencia, la instancia sigue viva y, por tanto, no será ejecutado su método `__del__` todavía. Si tienes cuidado para no tener ninguna referencia descontrolada a instancias de `Usuario` (eg: como variables globales) verás que se ejecuta el `__del__`. Si tenías una instancia raiz `padre`, borra ésa y todas las demás irán detrás.